# How do I remove the xsi prefix in SOAP::Lite generated XML?

Tags: xml, perl, soap

I am sending request from Soap::Lite. I am creating XML using SOAP::Data.  There is `xsi:type="xsd:string"` being added on each tag in the XML. How  can I remove this from all the tags?

I am creating xml like this :

```
SOAP::Data->type('string')->name('Desc')->value( 'Test'),
```

Comment: Do you want to remove only the prefix `xsi:` or the whole `xsi:type` attribute?

Comment: i want to remove whole xsi:type attr

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: The client is not accepting that in the request call

Comment: What if you remove the `->type('string')` from the chain? You may also need to call `autotype(0)` on the `SOAP::Lite` object.

Comment: @IanRoberts it's not working

Comment: @IanRoberts how we can add blank xmlns in each tag ??With autoType(0) it's working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `->type('string')` adds an explicit type to the element, so you need to remove this for starters.  But even without that `SOAP::Lite` defaults to "auto-typing" which will add the `xsi:type` attributes automatically, you need to suppress that behaviour as well, by calling `->autotype(0)` on the `SOAP::Lite` object.

The `SOAP::Lite` library has a long history, and dates from when "rpc/encoded" was the predominant type of SOAP service.  The "encoded" style requires the `xsi:type` attributes but the "document/literal" style (far more popular these days) does not.